# How to convert a string representation of a number to a number in coldfusion?

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

I want to be able to convert a string number such as "1,427.76" to a number in coldfusion but the comma is making it fail.  Is there a simple way to do it besides having to remove the comma?

```
<cfset string = "1,427.75">

<cfset number = string * 100>
```

The error occurs when trying to perform mathematical operations on it.  If the comma is removed it works just fine but I'm getting the comma from a database calculation.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I know you can use LSParseNumber:

```
<cfset string = "1,427.75">

<cfset number = LSParseNumber(string) * 100>
```

Comment: @Scott Chantry if derivation's answer worked for you, don't forget to choose it as the Accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 10):

Val() works as well for simple conversions where you don't care about locale, e.g. Val('123.45')

Comment: easy fixed with a string = val( string.replaceAll('[^0-9\.]+','') );

Comment: using val() is roughly 2x faster than lsParseNumber()

Comment: even faster to use string = ( string.replaceAll('[^0-9\.]+', '') * 1 );